# Python- Alternative terminal in Atom text editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

Right now I'm running Python in Atom with Platformio as my terminal. First off, what's the keyboard shortcut to run the file? Secondly, is there a better terminal package out there? I'd like more features such as right clicking and selecting run the file or something that makes running the file easier (maybe a run button). I switch between files quite frequently so I'd like an alternative other than using the up arrow to run previous command.

Answer (score 0):

I use Atom for python. The best terminal plugin I have found is Platformio. I have a plugin named script that allows me to run python scripts from the editor window. The command also has a shortcut to speed up the process. Load script and it will appear under the packages menu. It also defines the shortcut for 'run script' as the command-I keys.

Lately I've been running python script using the Hydrogen plugin. This allows in-line plotting along with running your script. Answers and plots appear in the editor pane. Its very nice if you have to plot.

Comment: Thanks jmh. I'll give those a try.